# Linq to SQL and outer apply

Tags: sql, linq, apply, outer-join

I'm trying to convert "SQL Outer Apply" to Linq.
The SQL is:

```
select Currencies.Name, Currencies.Sign ,a.ActualPrice 
from Currencies 
outer apply (select CurrencyID,ActualPrice from Prices 
where ProductID=5 and      Currencies.ID=Prices.CurrencyID)a
```

I have tried the following Linq but got one row, instead of row for each currency as the SQL statement gives me.

```
from c in Currencies 
from p in Prices.DefaultIfEmpty()
where p.ProductID.Equals(5) && c.ID==p.CurrencyID
select new {c.Name, p.ActualPrice}
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: your original query could easily be reqritten as a left outer join, and the following question covers at least one linq equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742814/left-outer-join-problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = 
    Currencies.Select(c => new
                      {
                          Name = c.Name, 
                          Sign = c.Sign, 
                          ActualPrice = Prices.Where(p => p.ProductID == 5 && 
                                                          p.CurrencyID == c.ID)
                                              .FirstOrDefault()
                      });
```

I am not sure if this returns the correct result, because I don't know what happens, when the subselect in `outer apply` returns multiple rows...

Comment: `OUTER APPLY` is equivilent to a `LEFT JOIN`, but on to a function of sub-query that is able to accept values from the records it is being joined on to.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. a bit recoded changed but that was the idea. '
                  select new ProductPrices
                  {
                      CurrencyName = c.Name,
                      Sign = c.Sign,
                      ActualPrice = (from p in ctx.Prices
                                     where p.ProductID == productId &&
                                     p.CurrencyID == c.ID
                                     select p.ActualPrice).FirstOrDefault(),
                      select p.FullPrice).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0
                  }'